# База данных MNIST

Tags: база-данных, нейронные-сети

Работаю над нейронной сетью по распознованию цифр, для обучение использую базу данных MNIST, требуется доучить нейронною сеть - не могу найти как самому написать похожую базу со своими обучающими примерами как в MNIST. Желательно с полным объяснением как устроены данные в MNIST

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данные устроены очень просто. Если откроете файлик mnist_train.csv в блокноте, то каждая текстовая строка - это изображение размером 28*28, развёрнутое построчно в одну текстовую строку. Числа - яркость пикселей, первое число - правильный ответ. в каждой строке 28*28+1 значений. Всего в базе 60000 изображений - 60000 строк в файле.

Answer (score 0):

MNIST содержит коллекцию из  70 000 изображений 28 x 28  рукописных цифр от  0 до 9.
Набор данных разделен на наборы для обучения и тестирования. Загрузка

from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist #Библиотека с базой Mnist
(x_train_org, y_train_org), (x_test_org, y_test_org) = mnist.load_data() #Загрузка данных Mnist

x_train_org - 60000 тренировочных картинок 28 x 28  рукописных цифр от  0 до 9 в бело -серых тонах

y_train_org - цифры на картинках в виде чисел 0-9

то-же самое для тестирования-проверки обученной нейронной сети  10000 тестовых картинок
x_test_org, y_test_org

Как написать похожую базу:

- На бумаге рисуем произвольную цифру. Небольшого размера ( клетка тетради).
- Фотографируем
- Загружаем фото
- С помощью функции image.load_img(path, target_size=(28, 28), color_mode = ‘grayscale’) загружаем картинку в переменную.

Comment: и каким образом написанное вами отвечает на вопрос «как самому написать похожую базу со своими обучающими примерами как в MNIST»? ведь ответ на просьбу («Желательно с полным объяснением как устроены данные в MNIST») уже написан три года назад в соседнем ответе.

Comment: В соседнем ответе есть неточности по MNIST. А обьяснение - На бумаге рисуем произвольную цифру.
- Фотографируем
- Загружаем фото
- С помощью функции image.load_img(path, target_size=(28, 28), color_mode = ‘grayscale’) загружаем картинку в переменную.

Comment: дополните, пожалуйста, ваш ответ, нажав [edit]