# Как подготовить набор данных для сверточной нейронной сети в TensorFlow 2.0 (python 3)

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, tensorflow, dataset

Мне понятно как это можно сделать для общедоступных наборов данных, например "mnist"

```
dataset = tfds.load( 'horses_or_humans' , split=tfds.Split.TRAIN )
```

Как получить 'dataset' в том же формате для своего набора изображений. Например, в папке "My_Dataset" есть две папки с изображениями, "Class-1" и "Class-2" ?

Comment: попробуйте произветси декомпозицию вашего очень широкого вопроса, и сосредоточиться на первом из пунктов. например: как вообще прочитать и представить в виде массива изображение в таком-то формате.

Comment: в принципе [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/817550/178576), хотя ответа «как сделать» там фактически нет. хотя, может быть, автор [сегодняшнего ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1252920/178576) что-нибудь и напишет.

Comment: вот ещё один тоже как бы [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1165177/178576)

Comment: Спасибо за комментарии, там действительно пока нет ответа на вопрос.
А тем временем, сначала решил пойти по этому пути : [Создание собственного набора данных](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/add_dataset). Но там не получилось сходу разобраться, все оказалось сложнее. Сейчас хочу сам создать и сформировать объект "dataset". На сомом деле - это словарь, следующего вида : 
'{
        'image': Image(shape=(300, 300, 3), dtype=tf.uint8),
        'label': ClassLabel(shape=(), dtype=tf.int64, num_classes=2),
    })'

Comment: Я прошу прощения, в самом изначальном вопросе исправил: "mnist" на "horses_or_humans". Меня интересует входные данные, как каталог с уже готовыми изображениями, а не в виде CSV файла, как в "mnist".

Comment: Продублировал вид словаря в удобно-читаемой форме:
`{ 'image': Image(shape=(300, 300, 3), dtype=tf.uint8), 'label': ClassLabel(shape=(), dtype=tf.int64, num_classes=2), }`

Comment: И в этом направлении оказалось не все так просто. Хоть это и словарь, но какой то не простой словарь. По запросу `print(type(dataset))`, отдает >>>> `class 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.PrefetchDataset'`